# Responsive bootstrap grid with 6 columns of equal heights

Tags: views, theming, bootstrap-theme

In the front page of our website, I would like to list down groups led by researchers and each group is having a thumbnail picture and a title where the picture is of fixed width/height but, the title is not (could be small or large - title appearing a the bottom of the image).

For some reason the grid is not displaying properly and I feel like it is due to the big/small titles of the groups which cause this issue. Column heights could be an issue.

My settings are as follow:

Drupal 7
Views 3 (Block and/or Page) 
Unformatted 
Fields

http://www.bootply.com/wtGxTJjXva  (I have 18 divs and they have to be divided into six in each row but, it does not) - could anyone point out what I am missing?

[image]

According to the image, first row and last column is showing two divs rather than one and in second row I got three divs squeezing into single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a proper solution to this issue however, fixed the problem with giving each div (within row class) a height of 200px and it perfectly organized everything.

I can use viewports to assign an appropriate height (than 200px for all displays) for different views.

Answer (score 2):

You should use '**Bootstrap Grid**' format for Views in some cases, which you'll be able to select after install/enable of the [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) module. Here is a quote about this module (from its project page):

> ... enables you to create components following the theme structure of the Bootstrap framework all within the configuration settings of the powerful [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

Comment: Great suggestion Peter! +1 from me ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and had tried jQuery/Javascript solutions or CSS. I ended up using the module [Views Responsive Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid). For a two column grid layout I edited the View and used these settings:

```
 Format: Responsive Grid
 Number of columns: 2
 Column classes: views-column col-sm-6 (for every column)
 Row classes: views-row clearfix (for every row)
```

In your case, since you want t 6 column grid, you would use the following settings for the Column Classes:

```
 views-column col-sm-2
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you list the items in a for/foreach loop, add

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

at after each 6<sup>th</sup> item. For example

```
$items = array(...);
$j = 0;

foreach($items as $i){
    if(++$j % 6 == 0){
        echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
    }
    echo '<div class="col-md-2">' . $i['key1'] . '</div>';

}
```

Thus, your items will be in order.